# How can I apply or destroy after removing resources via AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a module with various batch service resources such as job definition, compute environment, and job queue.

Today I was unable to perform `terraform apply` due to an error with updating one of these Batch related resources (unfortunately I have lost those initial error messages).

I have run into something like this before and cleared the hurdle by manually disabling/deleting the job queue. So I did that again via the AWS Console and ran `terraform apply`, however this time the plan/apply still didn't work, perhaps because the queue had a single outstanding job in runnable but unstarted state (the previous times I've done this successfully the job queue was empty). So I did the same thing with the compute environment (disabled/deleted via AWS Console) and now I get messages such as this with `terraform plan`:

```
2020/04/30 15:15:43 [ERROR] module.batch_data_load: eval: *terraform.EvalRefresh, err: One compute environment is expected, but AWS return no compute environment
2020/04/30 15:15:43 [ERROR] module.batch_data_load: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: One compute environment is expected, but AWS return no compute environment
```

So it seems that I've bungled my state file by monkeying with the Terraform managed resources via AWS Console.

How can I apply or destroy after removing resources via AWS Console?

Comment: The full resource namespace in the error is `module.batch_data_load`?

Comment: probably `terraform refresh`

Comment: Yes, that's the name of the module which contains various `aws_iam_role`, `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment`, `aws_security_group`, `aws_batch_compute_environment`, `aws_batch_job_queue`, and `aws_batch_job_definition` resources.

Comment: `terraform refresh` gives the same error (thanks anyway for your suggestion!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform does try to resynchronize its own idea of the state with the remote objects as part of creating a plan, but it doesn't always work because sometimes remote objects interact in ways Terraform can't account for, or other reasons where Terraform doesn't have enough information to fully resynchronize.

If you know that the remote object associated with a particular resource instance in your configuration is deleted, you can tell Terraform to "forget" that object and remove it from the state altogether, using the `terraform state rm` command:

```
terraform state rm aws_batch_job_queue.example
```

You should do this only if you know for certain that the object no longer exists, or if you intend to continue managing the existing object using some other system, because once Terraform has forgotten about the object it will never plan to destroy it and so the object can be left active forever.

Comment: Thanks for this useful insight, Martin.